# What does this symbol means?

Tags: notification-icons

[image]

My friend is asking about this icon on the notification bar. Is it from a application or just find in page?

Answer (score 2):

Good question and being a developer I know that an app can add their own icons to the notification bar.

Depending on your phone type you can long hold on an empty part of your screen and then down at the bottom you will see widgets.   Hit that and then scroll down or sideways to see if you have the Notification history widget.   If you do drag it to a place on your screen.   Then you can see what that notification is for.

If you don't have the notification widget you can install a notification history app that will show you your notifications and what they are for.

On the app that I downloaded while I was researching this answer I had to enable Save Non-removable notifications.

If the notification is on the left top then you should be able to swipe down and see what app it is for.

If the notification is on the right you MAY be able to see it in the notification app.

That icon does not look like a default android icon so it's probably an application .

Here is a list of a lot of icons and it might be in there as well.
https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline